# sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess for access notesdocument with reader field

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a database with documents with readers field where there are the signer as only Reader.

I need to open an Xpages for a public access that show evenry document in edit-mode with URL:

`http://PATHDB/Edit.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=UNID`

There are a solution for open the datasource with sessionasSigner credential and show and edit the fields?

Tnx

Comment: seems to be security threat to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find an example how this can be realized:
http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=723

Comment: Nice blog post!
Why not include a copy of the blog post here, just avoiding broken future broken links etc. ?  ;-)

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a managed bean instead of a document datasource and build all the logic into that? Gives you full control over how the data is retrieved/ stored and should solve the issue you're having.

You can start with [this](http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html) article on how to use managed beans in XPages.